# How do I define a List of Collections in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I want to define a list, in which each node will point to a differnt kind of collection.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to define a list, in which each node will point to a differnt
>   kind of collection.

```
    List<Collection<TypeYouWanted>> list = new ArrayList<Collection<TypeYouWanted>>();
    list.add(new ArrayList<TypeYouWanted>());
    list.add(new HashSet<TypeYouWanted>());
```

Comment: Ideally, of course, you'd have an actual parameter to `Collection` as well, e.g. `List<Collection<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

Just use generics: `List<Collection> list = new Arraylist<Collection>();`

It defines a list of collections... each entry in your list must be an implementation of `Collection` but not necessarily the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Its generally not a good programming practise to create a list of different kinds of objects. This is because, unless carefully coded, u have no idea what you will get in a specific place in the list. That said, you can have a list object such as

```
List<Collection> collList = new ArrayList<Collection>();
```

and add whatever object you need into this list.